# How to press ⌥ ⌘ / shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts-app

I use a 13" MacBook M1 Pro.

On [JetBrains' documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/mps/commenting-and-uncommenting-blocks-of-code.html), it says to use

> ⌥ ⌘ /

for commenting blocks of code. I tried pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> keys at the same time but it doesn't work. How can I achieve using this shortcut? I also stumbled upon another shortcut: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, I tried pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd> at the same time and failed.

[image: Comment and uncomment blocks of code shortcut]

Keyboard layout is Turkish…

[image]

Comment: Why 7 or 9 ? What's your Keyboard layout  and Input Language? Post a photo if you aren't sure.

Comment: It has Turkish QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look further in the jetbrains doc at the Troubleshoot section:

[image]

Comment: Oh my bad! So it is impossible in my Turkish QWERTY keyboard to use these shortcuts so i have to assign myself :(